# Delete last string suffix vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm wondering if there is a way more efficient approach in deleting the last string value in a cell value.

In my case I need to delete a suffix i.e

```
TNV1602000014C      //delete suffix C 
117239B             //delete suffix B
MRV117299           //nothing to delete
115365Z             //delete suffix Z
```

I've tried this approach

```
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row  
Range("E2:E" & lastrow).Formula = "=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(RC[-1],""A"",REPT("""",LEN(RC[-1]))),LEN(RC[-1])))"
```

but since I need to do this for the whole A-Z.
is there any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slightly simpler formula approach:

```
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
Range("E2:E" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=left(RC[-1],LEN(RC[-1])-ISERROR(RIGHT(RC[-1])+0))"
```

You could also do it in place using `Evaluate` if you wanted.

Comment: nice Rory, very nice

Comment: @brettdj : As usual!^^

Comment: gahddd.. Thanks! much simpler and cleaner. :D

Answer (score 1):

The below will loop any selected cells and if the last character is a letter (not a number or special character) then the last character in the cell will be removed

```
 Sub RemoveTrailingLetter()
    Dim c As Range

    'Replace Selection With Your Range
    For Each c In Selection
        'If The Last Character Is A Letter
        If IsLetter(Right(c, 1)) Then
            'Remove The Last Character
            c = Left(c, Len(c) - 1)
        End If
    Next c

End Sub

Function IsLetter(strValue As String) As Boolean
Dim intPos As Integer

    For intPos = 1 To Len(strValue)
        Select Case Asc(Mid(strValue, intPos, 1))
            Case 65 To 90, 97 To 122
                IsLetter = True
            Case Else
                IsLetter = False
                Exit For
        End Select
    Next

End Function
```

Comment: Why not use `Not IsNumeric(...)` rather than creating a function for that?

Comment: @R3uK That would allow punctuation, which I don't believe the original poster needed

Comment: @JiminyCricket : Nah, ponctuation isn't considered a numeric with `IsNumeric`... And BTW, you should **rather use `AscW` than `Asc`** because special characters will return an almost random number with `Asc` because it doesn't fit into the format that it is using! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Paste this in a module in the workbook you need to use it.
It'll get rid of all non numeric suffix (you might have more than one character to remove).
You can directly use it in Excel, like `=RemoveSuffix(D1)` or in a VBA loop

```
Public Function RemoveSuffix(ByVal StringToClean As String) As String
    Dim i As Integer

    If IsNumeric(Right(StringToClean, 1)) Then
        RemoveSuffix = Trim(StringToClean)
    Else
        i = 1
        Do While Not IsNumeric(Mid(StringToClean, Len(StringToClean) - i, 1))
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        RemoveSuffix = Trim(Left(StringToClean, Len(StringToClean) - i))
    End If
End Function
```

To fill column E :

```
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row  
Range("E2:E" & lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=RemoveSuffix(RC[-1])"
```

Or to overwrite column D :

```
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
for i = 2 to lastrow  
    Cells(i,4).Value = RemoveSuffix(Cells(i,4).Value)
next i
```

Comment: Thanks for this :D

Comment: @Anne : You are welcome! This will be very useful if you have multiple characters to remove, but Rory's formula is pretty neat if you only have one to remove! ;)

Comment: I'll keep this also in my code bible :D thanks for your effort ! :D